# Data type for worksheets array

Tags: excel, vba

With the code below, I define an array of worksheets and run a For-Each-Loop over that array. I don't understand why I have to declare the variable `wsArray` as ***variant*** data type. Also, why I can't I just run the For-Each-Loop over the array using the instruction `For Each ws In wsArray`.

```
Sub TestWorksheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsArray As Variant
    
    ws = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    
    For Each ws In Worksheets(wsArray)
    
    ' ...do whatever
    
    Next ws
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Because of using `Array` function which returns variant data type ;)

Comment: Here `ws` is declared as `worksheet` and is being assigned as `string array`

Comment: "why I can't I just run the For-Each-Loop over the array" - what's the exact problem you get?

Comment: read the first paragraph at [MS Help `Array function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/array-function): *The `Array function` "Returns a Variant containing an array."* @D3merzel

Comment: You can't assign a (variant) array to `ws` that has been declared as worksheet, neither by simple assignment `ws = ...`, nor by `Set ws = ...`. Maybe you just tumbled apon the similar variable `ws` vs. `wsArray` as sort of typo instead of coding: `wsArray = Array("Tabelle1", "Tabelle2")` @D3merzel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Loop Through Several Worksheet

- In the first example, the worksheets in `wsNamesList` have to exist or the loop will cause a run-time error.
- In the second more flexible example, only the existing worksheets will be 'processed'.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TestWorksheets()

    Const wsNamesList As String = "Sheet2,Sheet3"
    
    Dim wsNames() As String: wsNames = Split(wsNamesList, ",")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets(wsNames)
        Debug.Print ws.Name, ws.UsedRange.Address
    Next ws
    
End Sub

Sub TestWorksheetsMoreFlexible()

    Const wsNamesList As String = "Sheet2,Sheet3"
    
    Dim wsNames() As String: wsNames = Split(wsNamesList, ",")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To UBound(wsNames)
        Set ws = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsNames(n))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print ws.Name, ws.UsedRange.Address
        End If
    Next n
    
End Sub
```

### EDIT

```
Sub TestWorksheetsVariant()

    Const wsNamesList As String = "Sheet2,Sheet3"
    
    Dim wsNames() As String: wsNames = Split(wsNamesList, ",")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim nUpper As Long: nUpper = UBound(wsNames)
    Dim wss() As Worksheet: ReDim wss(0 To nUpper)
    
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To nUpper
        Set wss(n) = wb.Worksheets(wsNames(n))
    Next n
    
    Dim ws As Variant ' ***
    For Each ws In wss
        Debug.Print ws.Name, ws.UsedRange.Address
    Next ws
    
End Sub

Sub TestWorksheetsVariantShort()

    Dim wsArray As Variant: wsArray = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    
    Dim ws As Variant ' ***
    For Each ws In Worksheets(wsArray)
        Debug.Print ws.Name, ws.UsedRange.Address
    Next ws
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> why I have to declare the variable wsArray as variant data type

you don't declare the array, you declare a variant which can hold an array.
Array declaration would be something like

`Dim wsArray() as String`

Comment: `For Each` can loop through arrays.